# #1054 - Unknown column 'cg1.station_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, join

when running this script I get the above error:

```
SELECT s1.Station_Name as Station, s1.St_Town as Town, cg1.CaporGen as Type, ht1.HYDRO_NAME as Typology
FROM station s1, capacityandgeneration cg1, hydro_type ht1
JOIN station s2 ON cg1.station_id=s2.Station_ID
inner join hydro_type ht2 on cg2.hydro_type_id=ht2.type_id;
```

but when I remove the 3rd table it works fine:

```
SELECT s1.Station_Name as Station, s1.St_Town as Town, cg1.CaporGen as Type
FROM station s1, capacityandgeneration cg1
JOIN station s2 ON cg1.station_id=s2.Station_ID;
```

I've tried various permutations with column aliases but constantly get the above error. Please show me the error of my ways as I'm baffled at the moment.

Cheers Simon

Comment: does the column station_id exists in the table capacityandgeneration?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s1.Station_Name as Station, s1.St_Town as Town, cg1.CaporGen as Type, ht1.HYDRO_NAME as Typology
FROM station s1
join capacityandgeneration cg1
join hydro_type ht1
JOIN station s2 ON cg1.station_id=s2.Station_ID
inner join hydro_type ht2 on cg2.hydro_type_id=ht2.type_id;
```

Try this. If the columns exists, then there should not be any problem

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I was sitting at this all morning and couldn't fathom it out. I fixed it by removing all the tables bar the station table from the 'from' statement and then re-ordered the join statements as they were clearly in the wrong order. I've also added more tables to form a more complex join which works. The solution to the original posed question is......

Comment: SELECT s1.Station_Name as Station, s1.St_Town as Town, cg1.CaporGen as Type, ht1.HYDRO_NAME as Typology
FROM station s1
inner join capacityandgeneration as cg1 on s1.Station_ID=cg1.station_id 
inner join hydro_type as ht1 on cg1.hydro_type_id=ht1.type_id

Answer (score 0):

As documented under [`JOIN` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/join.html):

> #### Join Processing Changes in MySQL 5.0.12
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> The following list provides more detail about several effects of current join processing versus join processing in older versions. The term “previously” means “prior to MySQL 5.0.12.”
>
> ```
> [ deletia ]
> ```
>
> - Previously, the comma operator (`,`) and `JOIN` both had the same precedence, so the join expression `t1, t2 JOIN t3` was interpreted as `((t1, t2) JOIN t3)`. Now `JOIN` has higher precedence, so the expression is interpreted as `(t1, (t2 JOIN t3))`. This change affects statements that use an `ON` clause, because that clause can refer only to columns in the operands of the join, and the change in precedence changes interpretation of what those operands are.
>
>   Example:
>
>   ```
>   CREATE TABLE t1 (i1 INT, j1 INT);
>   CREATE TABLE t2 (i2 INT, j2 INT);
>   CREATE TABLE t3 (i3 INT, j3 INT);
>   INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1,1);
>   INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1,1);
>   INSERT INTO t3 VALUES(1,1);
>   SELECT * FROM t1, t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
>   ```
>
>   Previously, the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html) was legal due to the implicit grouping of `t1,t2` as `(t1,t2)`. Now the `JOIN` takes precedence, so the operands for the `ON` clause are `t2` and `t3`. Because `t1.i1` is not a column in either of the operands, the result is an `Unknown column 't1.i1' in 'on clause'` error. To allow the join to be processed, group the first two tables explicitly with parentheses so that the operands for the `ON` clause are `(t1,t2)` and `t3`:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM (t1, t2) JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
>   ```
>
>   Alternatively, avoid the use of the comma operator and use `JOIN` instead:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 JOIN t3 ON (t1.i1 = t3.i3);
>   ```
>
>   This change also applies to statements that mix the comma operator with `INNER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, and `RIGHT JOIN`, all of which now have higher precedence than the comma operator.